# Problem with sudo apt update command

Tags: proxy, repository, software-sources

I am on a proxy server. Please find below details when I execute `sudo apt update` in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:4 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease                            
Get:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Err:6 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release    
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Get:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [299 kB]
Get:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [195 kB]
Get:10 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [162 kB]
Hit:8 http://apt.llvm.org/trusty llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.7 InRelease          
Get:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [203 kB]
Ign:12 https://repo.iovisor.org/apt/xenial xenial-nightly InRelease
Get:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.520 B]
Get:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.328 B]
Hit:15 https://repo.iovisor.org/apt/xenial xenial-nightly Release
Get:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.976 B]
Ign:17 https://repo.iovisor.org/apt/xenial xenial-nightly Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to get a **clean** output from `sudo apt update` command again?

Thank you in advance and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the `sbt` thing you can remove it

In Settings>Software&Updates select second tab ie Other Software

Select the entry `https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian` and click remove

---

If you just want to get rid of the error

use `sudo apt update --allow-insecure-repositories`

Comment: "sbt" error is gone, how to remove these "Hit:1" lines?

Comment: They are not errors.

Comment: Yah, but anyway I can clean them as well?

Comment: `Hit` means the old copy in your cache matches the current one on the server. And they are not downloaded again

Comment: Sorry to crib this again, but can we just delete these old copies from our caches?

Comment: Try sudo apt -qq update

Comment: dint help :! got the hits again ):

Comment: @SH' Then `sudo apt-get update > /dev/null` may be an option. It will suppress any normal output, keeping errors only.

Answer (score 0):

You must first add public key for the repository

Download the key with this link

https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=sbt

Then add it to apt using

`sudo apt-key add sbt-public.key.asc`

Then update

`sudo apt update`

Comment: 1) I am on a proxy-server, hence unable to download the key and follow the update 2) Can I just get rid of this "sbt" thing without downloading anything?

Comment: @Melebius, Is there any way I do not download "sbt" and remove these "hit" "ign" "err" lines when I run apt update? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SH' See my answer :)